# X-Frame-Options Forbidden iFrame on Apache2

Tags: linux, apache2, x-frame-options

Hello I am trying to display a part of an website in an iFrame. For example: IP 1.1.1.1 wants to iframe 1.1.1.2.
In apache2 security.conf it is set to:

`Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"`

I tried a lot of different forms of ALLOW FROM but nothing worked. I guess those solutions are outdated.

header module from apache 2 is enabled.

Is there any workaround on that? It is really a simple displaying which costs way too much time :D

Tyvm for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

ALLOWFROM is not supported in most browsers. Instead you should set Content-Security-Policy with "frame-ancestors 'self' ", where  would be the other host or ip that should be able to frame. You could add multiple sources if you like, not like X-Frame-Options which is limited to one source.